# Meteor JS Template event replace text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, meteor

Using Meteor JS, I would like to change the value of a span inside a Template.event on input keyup.

Something like this :

```
 Template.myTemplate.events({
     "keyup .convertInput": function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var t = event.target;
        $(t).parent().find('.resultConvertedAmount').html('1234');
     }
 });
```

Html :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control convertInput" />
    <span class="resultConvertedAmount"></span>
</div>
```

"resultConvertedAmount" is the destination span for which i would like to bind a value everytime a key is pressed on "convertInput".

The following code is a jQuery way to do it (this works fine) :

```
$('.convertInput').parent().find('.resultConvertedAmount').html('1234');
```

Any help ? thanks

Comment: Replace `t` with `event.currentTarget` in fifth line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a reference to your template instance so you don't need to traverse the dom.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
     "keyup .convertInput": function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        template.$('.resultConvertedAmount').html('1234');
     }
 });
```

The `template.$()` notation is a feature of spacebars/blaze and allows for you to use jquery selectors that are bound within the context of the template.

Comment: This works fine and its faster, i wasn't aware of template.$
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already binding the value `1234` to the span `.resultConvertedAmount` every time a key is pressed on `.convertInput`. If you want to replace the text in the span with what you enter in the text input, you could do one of the following -

```
$(t).parent().find('.resultConvertedAmount').html(t.value);
```

OR

```
template.find(".resultConvertedAmount").innerHTML = t.value;
```